# Web API not compressing response content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I have a WebAPI and I configure compression in WebApiConfig:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
```

In my winforms client, I use a HttpClient like this:

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
};

client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new ClientCompressionHandler(handler, new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serverUrl);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Both server and client projects reference:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression/

When I make a request to the api, with or without using compression, the content length is always the same. So I don't know if the content is being compressed or not.

IIS applicationhost.config specific to compression looks like this:

```
    <httpCompression directory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%IIS_BIN%\gzip.dll" />
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
            <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xml; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

I checked the %TEMP% folder and there is no subfolder named iisexpress, so I have to assume that using the above config doesn't enabled compression.

Is there a way to check if the content is compressed before it's being deserialized?

And if with the above code, does the api compress the response? Or is it a setting in IIS Express?

Comment: There are some thresholds concerning times-called and overall-size i think which determine whether a response should be gzipped or not. Also note that if testing in the IE that the IE dev-console is not showing the GZIP information since it is  unpacking the stuff in advance. You'll have to use Chrome or another developer friendly browser for that.

Comment: The returned content length for a particular object is always 1896, no matter if asking for compressed content or not. I'm checking the content size directly in Visual Studio 2012 whilst debugging.

Comment: Have you check if the GZIP feature is installed? (windows-functions / Internetinformationservices / performance / static AND dynamic compression. There is also a web.config / machine-config entry for dynamic compression and for which file-extensions it should be activated.

Comment: It looks like it is configured. Edited my question to include the IIS config part

Comment: Can you try to create a larger test-response? Compression itself is expensive too and the IIS might just drop the compression if it's not worth it.

Comment: Now I'm returning content having 550k bytes. Same size with or without compression.